# Error creating edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorImpl

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am running the cort coreference resolution from [this](https://github.com/smartschat/cort/blob/master/COREFERENCE.md) github repo. Using the syntax to run the system on raw input text as follows:

```
cort-predict-raw -in *.txt \ 
           -model model.obj \
           -extractor cort.coreference.approaches.mention_ranking.extract_substructures \
           -perceptron cort.coreference.approaches.mention_ranking.RankingPerceptron \
           -clusterer cort.coreference.clusterer.all_ante \
           -corenlp /home/kenden/deeshacodes/corenlp \
```

I get the following error :-

```
Exception in thread "main" edu.stanford.nlp.util.ReflectionLoading$ReflectionLoadingException: Error creating edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorImpl
    at edu.stanford.nlp.util.ReflectionLoading.loadByReflection(ReflectionLoading.java:40)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorFactory.create(TimeExpressionExtractorFactory.java:57)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorFactory.createExtractor(TimeExpressionExtractorFactory.java:38)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.regexp.NumberSequenceClassifier.<init>(NumberSequenceClassifier.java:86)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERClassifierCombiner.<init>(NERClassifierCombiner.java:132)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations.ner(AnnotatorImplementations.java:121)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorFactories$6.create(AnnotatorFactories.java:273)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:152)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:451)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:154)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:150)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:137)
    at corenlp.JsonPipeline.initializeCorenlpPipeline(JsonPipeline.java:206)
    at corenlp.SocketServer.main(SocketServer.java:102)
Caused by: edu.stanford.nlp.util.MetaClass$ClassCreationException: MetaClass couldn't create public edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorImpl(java.lang.String,java.util.Properties) with args [sutime, {}]
    at edu.stanford.nlp.util.MetaClass$ClassFactory.createInstance(MetaClass.java:237)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.util.MetaClass.createInstance(MetaClass.java:382)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.util.ReflectionLoading.loadByReflection(ReflectionLoading.java:38)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:466)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.util.MetaClass$ClassFactory.createInstance(MetaClass.java:233)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at de.jollyday.util.CalendarUtil.<init>(CalendarUtil.java:42)
    at de.jollyday.HolidayManager.<init>(HolidayManager.java:66)
    at de.jollyday.impl.DefaultHolidayManager.<init>(DefaultHolidayManager.java:46)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.time.JollyDayHolidays$MyXMLManager.<init>(JollyDayHolidays.java:148)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:466)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:556)
    at de.jollyday.caching.HolidayManagerValueHandler.instantiateManagerImpl(HolidayManagerValueHandler.java:60)
    at de.jollyday.caching.HolidayManagerValueHandler.createValue(HolidayManagerValueHandler.java:41)
    at de.jollyday.caching.HolidayManagerValueHandler.createValue(HolidayManagerValueHandler.java:13)
    at de.jollyday.util.Cache.get(Cache.java:51)
    at de.jollyday.HolidayManager.createManager(HolidayManager.java:168)
    at de.jollyday.HolidayManager.getInstance(HolidayManager.java:148)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.time.JollyDayHolidays.init(JollyDayHolidays.java:57)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.time.Options.<init>(Options.java:90)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorImpl.init(TimeExpressionExtractorImpl.java:44)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorImpl.<init>(TimeExpressionExtractorImpl.java:39)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:532)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:186)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:473)
    ... 39 more
```

I have tried corenlp version 3.5.2, 3.6.0 as well as 3.7.0 but nothing works. Where would I be going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure you use the proper dependencies with the proper version.

If you use Stanford CoreNLP 3.7.0, make sure you also have the latest lib and liblocal folders.

I believe this error is because you have an incompatible dependency jar somewhere.

Update:  This is an error due to Java 9.  Add this flag

```
--add-modules java.se.ee
```

and it should go away.

Comment: I have downloaded the latest version(3.7.0) from the main site. Yet the error persists.

Comment: You need to make sure you have all those dependency jars in your CLASSPATH.

Comment: @StanfordNLPHelp.....I am willing to bet the conflict is in your own build....probably between Chinese and English models?

Comment: where to add --add-modules java.se.ee ?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to new Java problem. 
One way is to add this flag in first of your java command:
--add-modules java.se.ee
But I recommend to check your results with the older version of java (JDK 8) too. because my  result are not true in some cases with the newer java version.